# 2 backgrounds on a hover don't work on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, hover

I am trying to use 2 different backgrounds on a li a:hover in a horizontal menu. It seems to be working in FF and chrome but doesn't work on IE. 
Here is the css for the horizontal menu using css

```
#layTopMenu 
{ 
    position: relative; 
    width: 970px;
    height: 52px; 
    padding-top: 1px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 5; 
}
#layTopMenu ul
{ 
    position: relative; 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#layTopMenu ul li 
{ 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 1px; 
    background: transparent url(../images/divider.gif) right no-repeat;
}
#layTopMenu ul li a {  
    color: #fff; 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 20px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-align:center; 
    height: 49px; 
    line-height: 49px;
}
#layTopMenu ul li a:hover 
{ 
    color: #fff; 
    background:url(../images/nav_dot.gif) no-repeat center, url(../images/tab_hover_bg.gif) repeat-x; 
    text-align:center;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't take multiple backgrounds for versions < 9. More [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you testing? IE8 and before isn't going to support multiple backgrounds using CSS.

http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds